# Drawing Multiple identical pyramids in opengl ES 2.0

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to draw as many pyramids to fill up the space. I can draw a single pyramid, change its color etc. But, now, I want to draw a lot of pyramids that can fill the screen. I want to use a single set of vertices and indices.
The vertex and index with color information are as follows :

```
const Vertex Vertices [] = {
{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{-1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
2, 4, 3,
1, 4, 2,
0, 4, 1,
4, 0, 3
};
```

Can anybody help me with the code as, I know I am doing some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL ES 2.0 the only way you can do this is simply by re-rendering the pyramid in the different positions on the screen. What you're getting at is called 'instancing' and it's only supported in OpenGL ES 3.0, where you would have as you said one set of vertices and indices but you would issue a gl command to draw many instances of them, all the while in the fragment shader you would have a built-in variable "gl_InstanceID" that you would use to tell what current instance you're on.

There are some vendor-specific extensions that allow you to do instancing in OpenGL ES 2.0, such as NV_draw_instanced, but again that would only work for specific vendors